# Setting up Ignite cluster with one local and one GCP remote node

Tags: ignite

Configuration on local node is below:

[image]

Ports (48500-48520, 48100) on both local and GCP instance are open as verified by network tools `telnet` (from the local for the GCP) and `nc` (from the GCP console to the local instance).

The configuration on GCP node is the same except `[GCP-Node-IP]' is changed to the`[Local-Node-IP]'.

I see the following log message on local node. The remote node was started first. Both the local and GCP consoles do not show the topology snapshot.

> [22:58:31,463][WARNING][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#6%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi]
>   Failed to read magic header (too few bytes received)
>   [rmtAddr=/[GCP-Node-IP]:37605, locAddr=/192.168.0.40:48500]

Answer (score 0):

This message means that some other application tries to connect to Ignite. For example, you could get this message when did telnet to the discovery port. Another possible reason is misconfiguration - e.g. if one node is configured without SSL (default) and another with SSL, you will get the same message.

As for nodes not joining each other, make sure that the configuration you provided is the same on both nodes. This way it should work, unless there is NAT between them.

Comment: I have created a target instance in GCP as they are non-Nat`ed (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29938137/225866) and attached my VM to this target instance, and created the forwarding rules that match the firewall rules on the VM. I now use the forwarding-rule IP in the config. Nodes are still not joining. I can, as beofre, access the machines via telnet and nc, respectively using the forwarding-rule IP. The logs have no clue about not joining the grid.